# recursive function inside css method callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, recursion, callback

I am a newbie in javascript. please help me understand where exactly I am making mistake in my concept. The callback function which is a recursive call is not working as expected. The 'bell' is supposed to tinkle each time with a deg.

```
function tinkle(deg){
    $("#bell").css({
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)', 
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)', 
        'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'
    }, 'fast', 'swing',function(){ tinkle(deg); });
}
```

Comment: Did you make a call to it for the first time?

Comment: Are you sure CSS has a callback function ?

Comment: Please read: [.css() | jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/). There's no callback in the `.css()` method.

Answer (score 0):

the css method doesn't have a callback method. you can [read the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

You've have to call the function yourself, try a `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function (){
  // your jquery css code here
}, [some delay time]);
```